# Remove Translate and share options from selection menu on textview in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, textview

I am using **textIsSelectable** property on textview, it allows user to copy the text of textview. Now when i longpress on textview, the menu have copy, selectAll translate and share options. I don't want translate and share option in that menu..

I am using xamarin for development, Please help me.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Remove the share options, you could use :

```
public override void OnActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode)
{
    IMenu menu = mode.Menu;
    menu.RemoveItem(Android.Resource.Id.ShareText);

    base.OnActionModeStarted(mode);
}
```

But I can't find the translate id, as an alternative choice, you could custom a `ContextMenu` :

```
public override void OnCreateContextMenu(IContextMenu menu, View v, IContextMenuContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    base.OnCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.cmenu, menu);
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/select_all"
        android:title="select all"
    />
    <item android:id="@+id/copy"
        android:title="copy"
     />
</menu>
```

When you click the menu item :

```
public override bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case Resource.Id.select_all:
            //Select All the TextView text   
            return true;
        case Resource.Id.copy:
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)GetSystemService(ClipboardService);
            clipboard.Text = myTextView.Text;            
            return true;
        default:
            return base.OnContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```