# How to programmatically use the language translation function in iOS? [Swift 5]

Tags: ios, swift

I am aware that there is a `Translate` function in a text menu in `UITextView` in iOS
(see for example [Remove Translate and share options from selection menu on textview in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546938/remove-translate-and-share-options-from-selection-menu-on-textview-in-xamarin)).

[image]

I would like to use this function by myself without using the `Translate` menu. For example, I would like to translate an entire sentence displayed in a `UITextView` instead of translating only the selected parts.

Is there a specific `func` that we can use? How can I call this function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple's translate **API** is not available to the public.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650024

You can use Google's `GoogleMLKit/Translate` instead.

---

## Use `ML Kit` on iOS.

Add `GoogleMLKit/Translate` in your **podfile** by running the following command in the terminal.

```
pod 'GoogleMLKit/Translate', '3.1.0'
```

Read the **Instal** & **Getting started** sections on https://cocoapods.org/ if you have not set **cocoapods** or you do not know how to do so.

Google has written a very good sample code. It is straight forward.
Read from the **Translate a string of text** section onwards.

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation/ios

---

#### info:

You may find this link helpful.

https://maximbilan.medium.com/googletranslate-api-in-swift-a36489a84508

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and for suggesting an alternative approach, @mahan!

Comment: hi, does `GoogleMLKit/Translate` free?